# Making a typing test in C#

Tags: c#, forms, input, key

I am trying to make a typing test in C# by typing random words into a textbox. When the user is done typing the word I want them to be able to press space or enter to move onto the next word. If I could just get the program to recognize the input of the SPACEBAR or the ENTER key then I know how to do the rest. 
This is my code, what function would I need to add to my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace DesktopApplication
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    string[] randomWords = new string[] {
            "Adult",
            "Aeroplane",
            "Air",
            "Aircraft",
            "Carrier",
            "Airforce",
            "Airport",
            "Album",
            "Alphabet",
            "Apple",
            "Army",
            "Baby",
            "Baby",
            "Backpack",
            "Balloon",
            "Banana",
            "Bank",
            "Barbecue",
            "Bathroom",
            "Cappuccino",
            "Car",
            "Car",
            "Carpet",
            "Carrot",
            "Cave",
            "Chair",
            "Chess",
            "Drill",
            "Drink",
            "Drum",
            "Dung"};




    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Welcome to the typing test!";

        label2.Text = "Type all the words that appear in the box below";

        label3.Text = "";

        button1.Text = "Press when ready to begin";


    }

    private void label1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label3.Text = randomWords[new Random().Next(0, randomWords.Length)];

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Read this a reference. [Keypress Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should first search the web and community before asking questions here but anyway I try my best to help you.

Comment: @P.Pat How should I get enter and space keys in `KeyPress`?

Comment: @Emad it can be done with an `if` condition. Something like this `if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))` then do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code basically does the same thing as @Emad's answer but instead of `keydown` event it uses `keypress` event.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) || e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Space))
            {
                button1_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }
```

So everytime you hit enter or spacebar it would be the same as clicking the button to generate a new word or move to the next word.

Comment: Using this code all I get is a windows sound and I have tried just using a print method in the function to see if its recognizing and It doesn't recognize it. It just keeps spacing in the text box.

Comment: I copy pasted your code, added the textbox `keypress` event and tested if it works before posting an answer. If you think it does not work then either you added more codes not included in your post or you are testing other codes that is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think you have a text box name `txtInput` you override it's `KeyDown` event with event handler like this:

```
private void txtInput_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Space)
    {
        //Space is pressed. Process it here.
    }
}
```